# May someone explain to me exactly what is happening in this code block?

Tags: python

I don't understand how the mydoubler object which references the function myfunc is passing a parameter to 'a' inside the lambda expression.

What I do get is this:
There is a function 'myfunc' that takes a parameter 'n'. The function 'myfunc' returns a value using a lambda expression 'lambda a : a * n'.
The object mydouble is a reference to the function 'myfunc(2)' where mydoubler is 'return lambda a : a * 2'.

Does the reference also mean that 'mydoubler' acts just like myfunc(n) and therefore takes a parameter where that parameter must be the only other variable inside the function 'myfunc'. Such that mydoubler(a) really is:
'return lambda a : a * 2

```
    def myfunc(n):
        return lambda a : a * n

    mydoubler = myfunc(2)

    print(mydoubler(11))
```

No errors are returned, just me trying to understand what is happening.

Comment: `mydoubler = lambda a : a * n` which is a function that takes one argument. `mydoubler` is just a function. `myfunc` is just a function that returns a function, which gets assigned to the name `mydoubler` in the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

- lambda function is a small anonymous function
- A lambda function can take any number of arguments, but can only have one expression

the lambda function works as follows

```
lambda (args):return value
```

so basically its like any other function

consider the following example

```
x = lambda a, b : a * b
print(x(5, 6))
```

x now is like a function (function inside variable) such that you can call it whenever you want
...it takes a,b as parameters and returns a*b, so in this case the result would be 30

in your case you've lambda anonymous function inside python function, so what happen is 
you call ***myfunc*** passing n value it goes to lambda function and the function is returned (note that the lambda function is returned) you call the lambda function again with the given value and it return the result